# Storefront sticky header

Tags: html, css, wordpress, storefront

I am trying to create a sticky header for my WordPress site ([www.carryoneverything.com](https://www.carryoneverything.com)). I have the latest Storefront theme installed, but I can't seem to get my logo, navigation, cart, and search all on the same line. I think it is because they are all in seperate divs?

I want my header to look like https://www.hollisterco.com/shop/us when its done.

Additionally, the admin bar covers up the sticky header and the sticky header ccovers up the body when I do:

```
#masthead {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Can I solve this in CSS or do I have to use javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Add the css to style.css

```
#masthead {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
/*resizing the logo image */
#masthead.sticky .custom-logo-link img {
    width: auto;
    height: 40px;
}

/*positioning the main-navigation */
#masthead.sticky .main-navigation {
    text-align: right;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 300px;
    padding: 0;
    width: auto;
}


/*positioning the logo*/
#masthead.sticky .custom-logo-link {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
/*adjusting default margins and paddings*/
#masthead.sticky .site-header-cart .cart-contents{
    padding:1em 0;
}
#masthead.sticky .main-navigation ul.menu>li>a, .main-navigation ul.nav-menu>li>a {
    padding: 1em 1em;
}
#masthead.sticky .site-branding{
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

/*positioning the cart-menu */
#masthead.sticky .site-header-cart {
    width: 14% !important;
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 0;
    right: 12%;
    padding: 0;
}

/*applying the position fixed on the masterhead */
#masthead.sticky{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
/*removing the site search*/
#masthead.sticky .site-search{
    display:none;
}
}
```

Create a file “stickyheader.js” to the js folder of your theme. and add following code

```
(function($){
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
          if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100){  
            jQuery('#masthead').addClass('sticky');
          }
          else{
            jQuery('#masthead').removeClass("sticky");
          }
            });
}); 
})(jQuery);
```

Add this code to functions.php so that js file is included

```
$path = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/js/';
if (!is_admin()) wp_enqueue_script('stickyheader', $path.'stickyheader.js',
array('jquery'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely solve this with CSS. The parent container that holds the items you wish to line up can have flex attributes added so it will line things up for you. Read more about flex here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

When things are being covered up by giving a div a fixed position then it is most-likely a z-index issue. This lets you layer divs, keeping certain divs on top, and other on the bottom.

example:
`z-index:1` will be covered by `z-index:2`. Read more about z-index here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

```css
.parent{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-items:center;
}

.child{
  width:20%;
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    1
  </div><!-- child -->
    <div class="child">
    2
  </div><!-- child -->
    <div class="child">
    3
  </div><!-- child -->
</div><!-- parent -->
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a wordpress Issue. We can't just solve it by giving you a code.
We have to have access to the site.
The Theme may also provide some editing (Theme Options) for you.
It's actually a little problem, BTW.